# Insert result of multiple Select statements into one Table in their respective columns

Tags: t-sql, variables

I'm working on gathering some SQL Server Stats for upgrade planning. I found some good queries and modified it to fit my requirements. I would like to add the result from each query into a table (SQLSTATS) where the result will go into respective columns. I'm planning on running these queries every N minutes via a SQL Agent Job to collect the data. I will be presenting the finding to decide if we need to move to Disk Optimized, CPU Optimized, Memory Optimized, or Network Optimized servers. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Queries are below:

```
 --Disk I/O
    SELECT
        wait_time_ms/waiting_tasks_count AS 'PAGEIOLATCH_SH'
    FROM
       sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
    WHERE
       waiting_tasks_count > 0
   and wait_type = 'PAGEIOLATCH_SH'
ORDER BY
   wait_time_ms DESC

SELECT
    wait_time_ms/waiting_tasks_count AS 'PAGEIOLATCH_SH'
FROM
   sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
WHERE
   waiting_tasks_count > 0
   and wait_type = 'PAGEIOLATCH_EX'
ORDER BY
   wait_time_ms DESC


SELECT
    wait_time_ms/waiting_tasks_count AS 'PAGEIOLATCH_UP'
FROM
   sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
WHERE
   waiting_tasks_count > 0
   and wait_type = 'PAGEIOLATCH_UP'
ORDER BY
   wait_time_ms DESC


--Network
SELECT st.text AS [SQL_Text],
w.wait_type AS [Wait_Type]
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS w
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON w.session_id = c.session_id
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle))
AS st WHERE w.session_id > 50
AND w.wait_duration_ms > 0
AND WAIT_Type='ASYNC_NETWORK_IO'


--CPU
DECLARE @ts BIGINT;
DECLARE @lastNmin TINYINT;
SET @lastNmin = 1;
SELECT @ts =(SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info); 
SELECT TOP(@lastNmin)
        SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQLServer_CPU_Utilization]    
FROM (SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]','int')AS record_id, 
record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]','int')AS [SystemIdle], 
record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]','int')AS [SQLProcessUtilization], 
[timestamp]      
FROM (SELECT[timestamp], convert(xml, record) AS [record]             
FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers             
WHERE ring_buffer_type =N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'AND record LIKE'%%')AS x )AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

I have done some extensive searches online but could not find any answers related to my issue. I tried inserting the result of the query into a variable and then from variable into table -> column. It did not worked. See the code below:

```
Declare @PAGEIOLATCH_SH Nvarchar(50)
--IO Disk 
SET @PAGEIOLATCH_SH = (SELECT 
wait_time_ms/waiting_tasks_count AS 'PAGEIOLATCH_SH'
FROM
   sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
WHERE
   waiting_tasks_count > 0
   and wait_type = 'PAGEIOLATCH_SH')
PRINT @PAGEIOLATCH_SH

Select @PAGEIOLATCH_SH INTO SQLSTATS (pageiolatch_sh))
```

[Here's the query result set:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rve3O.png)

Comment: It would be helpful and I think easy to include a sample of the result set or the table you are wanting to put the merged/blended record into. Just for sake of clarity. I think I know what you are trying to get in the end, but it will help to eliminate an confusion. Just list a sample couple of rows from teh final result set you expect.

Comment: Hi Jamie, sorry for the delay as I got busy with other more urgent stuffs. I have edited the question with result set, please click on the link "Here's the query result set" to see the result. I want to be able to enter this result set in one row into a single table. The SQL Agent job will run every 15 minutes and enter this result and create new row each time that table.